# I want to overload a function with the same type parameter; what should I do?

Tags: c++, coding-style, qt, parameters, overload

I'm creating an API, and I want to overload a function for `strip`:

```
QString MyClass::strip();
QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression open);
QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression close);
QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression open, QRegularExpression close);
```

Obviously the second and third conflict.

What is the recommended style for C++ and Qt programmers to restructure this?

Comment: [Default arguments?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments)

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Does that solution work, when both parameters are not necessarily used? Think of it as "Dinner" and "Desert" ; Maybe I only want dinner, but not desert, or maybe I want desert, but not dinner. Maybe I want both! Maybe I want neither!

Comment: You should give your functions different names, like `stripOpen` and `stripClose`.

Comment: Just keep #4 and handle the case where open or close are null.

Comment: What gardenhead says. Don't be too smart about this. You may come up with a technical solution that works and feel good about it but you should first consider what it looks like at the client's end. Does it still read well? Is it obvious what your methods do when the user hits the dot and gets presented a list of methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about creating a class to hold your arguments? This class would contain both `open` and `close` parameters and either of them could be `NULL`. Then, there will be only one `strip` method with above class as argument and method will decide if it wants to use `open`/`close` if they are set.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion; I have never used this method. Can you give me an idea of what it would look like? Why a class, and not a struct?

Comment: @Akiva Well, I don't think it matters if struct or class in this case.

Comment: @Akiva C++ has *class types* defined with both `struct` and `class` keywords

Answer (score 5):

There are many options, it's your tradeoff which to take:

#### Decision at runtime:

1. Add a defaulted `bool` argument:

   ```
    QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression regex, bool close=false);
    // Mimic the two-regex-variants interface as good as possible
   ```
2. Use scoped enum's and no default as a variant on 1 which is more descriptive:

   ```
    enum class option { open, close };
    QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression regex, option open_close);
   ```
3. Use [`std::experimental::optional`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) or something like that, maybe [from boost](//www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).
4. Find out that a specific regex does nothing, and document that as the no-op default.

#### Decision at compiletime:

5. Use overloads replacing one argument with `std::nullptr_t`:

   ```
    QString MyClass::strip(std::nullptr_t open, QRegularExpression close);
    QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression open, std::nullptr_t close = {});
   ```
6. Use tags to avoid any overhead:

   ```
    constexpr struct open_t {} open;
    constexpr struct close_t {} close;
    QString MyClass::strip(open_t, QRegularExpression regex);
    QString MyClass::strip(close_t, QRegularExpression regex);

    // Call it like this:
    object.strip(object.open, regex);
   ```
7. Bite the bullet and name those functions differently:

   ```
    QString MyClass::strip_open(QRegularExpression regex);
    QString MyClass::strip_close(QRegularExpression regex);
   ```
8. Consider whether making the open-regex and the close-regex different types makes sense. To be truthful, I doubt it here, but where appropriate that's the best option.

Comment: 6. Don;t provide them Allow QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression open, QRegularExpression close); to take NULL parameters.

Comment: @mattnz Ohhh that is an interesting solution! Question is though; is there a naming scheme for the parameters that would indicate that null values are accepted? Perhaps Defaulting them both to "NULL" values?

Comment: @Akiva: Elaborated on a way to achieve something like that. As an aside, you can combine using an optional type, replacing positional arguments with `std::nullptr_t` and using a "do nothing"-regex.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest

```
QString MyClass::strip();
QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression regex, bool opening=false); 
QString MyClass::strip(QRegularExpression open, QRegularExpression close);
```

and perhaps

```
QString MyClass::strip_open(QRegularExpression regex);
QString MyClass::strip_close(QRegularExpression regex);
```

or replace the `bool opening` with e.g.

```
enum stripping_mode {Strip_Open, Strip_Close};;
```

or make even it a `class enum`